# Retrieving Facebook User Posts through Graph API 2.0

Tags: facebook-graph-api, access-token

I want to create and place a Facebook.com Redirection Link component on my web site. I would like this component to show data from the most recent Facebook Post, including content details like the Post comment and Photo (or Video Thumbnail).

When my web site user clicks on the component, I would like them to be redirected to my Facebook site.

This I hope will be easy to do. My concern is how to manage and acquire Long Living Access tokens.

I want to create a server component that logs into my Facebook page and retrieves my most current Facebook posts so I can cache this data on my server.  Once I have the most current Post comment and Photo (or Video Thumbnail) cached on my server, I will then display it in the Facebook.com Redirection Link component on my site. This caching component should be easy to create.

The hard part is, how will I generate an access token that the server component can use?

I am thinking of creating a "Facebook Access Token Generation web page" that my Facebook Account Admin person can go to, to enter my Facebook credentials. Once they have logged into my Facebook account, and granted the appropriate privileges, that web page will deliver the access token to the server. The server will then use the short term access token to generate a long term access token that will last for 60 days. Every 60 days the Facebook Account Admin will have to use this "Facebook Access Token Generation web page" to generate a new access token.

Is this what I need to do, or is there an easier way with Graph API 2.0?

I would rather just hard code an access token that never expires into the caching component, but from my understanding of the docs, I don't think this is possible.

Thank you!

Comment: Why can't you use the normal documented login flows? you should get a long-lived token automatically using the server side OAuth flows

Comment: @lgy My problem with the "Login on Client, API Calls from Client or Server" login flow for long-lived Server tokens is Step1: Client gets short-lived access token via login dialog. I don't want the Facebook admin to have to grant access "somehow" to create the token in the first place, or renew the long term token when it expires. Thank you!

Comment: @lgy I am the owner of the Facebook account, and will be granting access to my own website servers. I can write the code necessary to make all of the above processes happen, I just wondered if this is really what is required. I understand the degree of security this login flow enables, the access token user doesn't even have to inform the Facebook account owner what access token they have been given. I am just wondering, for Facebook account owners, is there an easier way to get a long term access token that does not expire unless it is disabled.

Comment: No, user access tokens are either short (~2 hours) or long (~60 days) expiry, but can be invalidated for other reasons - to access someone's data / access Facebook on their behalf they need to come back to your app or site periodically